# How to change between stack, queue and priority_queue?

Tags: c++

I need to write an algorithm that can examine a tree in different ways: depth first, breadth first or with a particular priority. I would use a template type for the data structure that holds the nodes to visit. But stack and (priority_)queue do not have the same interface.

How can i change between these data structures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your use case you can use the inserter from the stl. or you can create a template wrapper with specializations.

Comment: The problem is the top/front mismatch rather then the insert part. However I decided to create a wrapper pure virtual class and its specializations. Thank you.